# Using path as parameter in web application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, apache, web

I have a web server setup. And my web app (JQuery + HTML) is up and running. I would like to use the path that is provided in the URL as some variable and perform different operation.

E.g.

http://subdomain.mydomain.com/ 
This points to /var/www , and has my index.html

I am trying to achieve the functionality that, when path with some value is provided, e.g.

http://subdomain.mydomain.com/c3212

I will catch the value c3212 in javascript and set it as some static variable. The view/js code in index.html uses this code to make requests to server to fetch some data and layout the data accordingly.

How do I go about doing this ? Googling didn't help much, since I don't actually know what terms should I search for. Do I also need to make changes in Apache VirtualHost configuration?

I am not a web guy, help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: window.location will give you information regarding the current page. you can then use that info to base your functions on.

Comment: Are you looking to get this value in JS or on your server? You did mention javascript in your question, but if so, Apache VirtualHost has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Ya I am trying to get this value in JS. Ya I realized it might not have anything to do with VirtualHost config. What I am trying is basically to catch the url parameter /c3212 in my index.html/js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [window.location](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp) JavaScript object to get the path like so:

```
var path = window.location.pathname;
console.log(path); // this will output "/c3212" based on your example
```

Once you have this you can use it with the rest of your script.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Do I need to modify .htaccess in order to prevent NOT found ? and so that they will be caught under index.html ?